# PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 27, found: 36 Pager

Tags: android, android-glide

i'am new in android and i want build some image gallery app.i use this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/ and evry thinks worke fine for me.but i add load more and swiprefresh list to my Recylerview and evry thinks work fine for me .but when i scroll my Recyclerview and quickly i click one of my image i get this erro.

```html
The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 27, found: 36 Pager
```

this is my MainActiviy.

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String endpoint = "http:///get_cat.php";
    private ArrayList<Image> images;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private GalleryAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private int imagesize;

    //swip listener
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swiper;
    private String URL_TOP_250 = "http://...../getimage.php?page=";
    private String URL = "http://....../loadmore.php?page=";
    private int offSet = 1;
    private int page = 0;

    //load more

    //


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.MainActivity);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        swiper = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiper);




        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        images = new ArrayList<>();

        mAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), images,recyclerView);

        final LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 3);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);



        ///load more
        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new GalleryAdapter.OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                images.add(null);
               mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(images.size() - 1);

                fetchload();

            }
        });



//
        swiper.setOnRefreshListener(this);


        swiper.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            swiper.setRefreshing(true);
                            fetchMovies();
                            Config.offSet=1;


                        }
                    }
        );





        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new GalleryAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new GalleryAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("images", images);
                bundle.putInt("position", position);

                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                SlideshowDialogFragment newFragment = SlideshowDialogFragment.newInstance();

                    newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    newFragment.show(ft, "slideshow");


            }



            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));



       // fetchImages();

    }

    public void fetchImages() {

        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading json...");
        pDialog.show();

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(endpoint,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        pDialog.hide();

                        images.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Image image = new Image();
                                image.setName(object.getString("name"));

                                JSONObject url = object.getJSONObject("url");
                                image.setSmall(url.getString("small"));
                                image.setMedium(url.getString("medium"));
                                image.setLarge(url.getString("large"));
                                image.setTimestamp(object.getString("timestamp"));

                                images.add(image);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        fetchMovies();
        mAdapter.setPreviousTotal(false);
        Config.offSet=1;
    }

    private void fetchMovies() {

        // showing refresh animation before making http call
        swiper.setRefreshing(true);

        // appending offset to url
        String url = URL_TOP_250 + page;

        // Volley's json array request object
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        if (response.length() > 0) {

                            // looping through json and adding to movies list

                            images.clear();

                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Image image = new Image();
                                    image.setName(object.getString("name"));

                                    JSONObject url = object.getJSONObject("url");
                                    image.setSmall(url.getString("small"));
                                    image.setMedium(url.getString("medium"));
                                    image.setLarge(url.getString("large"));
                                    image.setTimestamp(object.getString("timestamp"));

                                    images.add(image);


                                    // updating offset value to highest value
                                    //if (rank >= offSet)
                                    //    offSet = rank;



                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }

                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        // stopping swipe refresh
                        swiper.setRefreshing(false);






                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // stopping swipe refresh
                swiper.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }



    private void fetchload() {
        // appending offset to url
        String url;
        if(Config.offSet==1){

            url = URL + (Config.offSet+1);

        }else {

            url = URL + Config.offSet;

        }



        // Volley's json array request object
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                            }
                        }, 3000);
                        images.remove(images.size() - 1);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(images.size());
                        
                        if (response.length() > 0) {

                            // looping through json and adding to movies list
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                    int rank = object.getInt("rank");

                                    Image image = new Image();
                                    image.setName(object.getString("name"));

                                    JSONObject url = object.getJSONObject("url");
                                    image.setSmall(url.getString("small"));
                                    image.setMedium(url.getString("medium"));
                                    image.setLarge(url.getString("large"));
                                    image.setTimestamp(object.getString("timestamp"));


                                    images.add(image);




                                    // updating offset value to highest value
                                    if (rank >= Config.offSet){
                                        Config.offSet = rank;
                                    }

                                    mAdapter.setLoaded();


                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }


                           mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());



                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }


}
```

SlideshowDialogFragment.java

```html
public class SlideshowDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private String TAG = SlideshowDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private ArrayList<Image> images;

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    private TextView lblCount, lblTitle, lblDate;
    private int selectedPosition = 0;
    private int myPosition = 0;

    //image
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ProgressBar bar;
    private int selectedindex;
    private boolean mPageEnd;
    private boolean callHappened;
    private int myCount;

    private View mContentView;
    private View mLoadingView;
    private int mShortAnimationDuration;


    static SlideshowDialogFragment newInstance() {
        SlideshowDialogFragment f = new SlideshowDialogFragment();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_slider, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        lblCount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl_count);
        lblTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        lblDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);

        bar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBarImage);



        images = (ArrayList<Image>) getArguments().getSerializable("images");

        selectedPosition = getArguments().getInt("position");

        Log.e(TAG, "position: " + selectedPosition);
        Log.e(TAG, "images size: " + images.size());


        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());


        setCurrentItem(selectedPosition);
        //load new image


        return v;
    }

    private void setCurrentItem(int position) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false);
        displayMetaInfo(selectedPosition);
    }


    //  page change listener
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            displayMetaInfo(position);
            selectedindex = position;
        }


        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

           /*
            if( mPageEnd && arg0 == selectedindex && !callHappened)
            {
                Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Okay");
                mPageEnd = false;//To avoid multiple calls.
                callHappened = true;
                fetchload();
            }else
            {
                mPageEnd = false;
            }
            */


        }


        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            /*
            if(selectedindex == myViewPagerAdapter.getCount() - 1)
            {
                mPageEnd = true;

            }

                */

        }
    };


    private void displayMetaInfo(int position) {
        lblCount.setText((position + 1) + " of " + images.size());

        Image image = images.get(position);
        lblTitle.setText(image.getName());
        lblDate.setText(image.getTimestamp());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

    }


    //  adapter
    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {

        }


        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fullscreen_preview, container, false);

            ImageView imageViewPreview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);

            if (images.get(position) != null) {

                Image image = images.get(position);


                Glide.with(getActivity())
                        .load(image.getLarge())
                        .thumbnail(0.5f)
                        .crossFade()
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .into(imageViewPreview);

                container.addView(view);
            } else {

                Glide.clear(imageViewPreview);
                imageViewPreview.setImageBitmap(null);
            }


            return view;
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {



            return images.size();
        }


        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

                return POSITION_NONE;
        }



        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == ((View) obj);
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

            container.removeView((View) object);

        }
    }
}
```

Galleryadapter.java

```html
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Image> images;
    private Context mContext;


    ////more load button>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    //neshan dahandehe noe layout
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;
    //tarife interface
    private OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener;
    //----------------
    private boolean isLoading;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerViewlist;

    private int visibleItemCount, totalItemCount, firstVisibleItem;
    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;



    ////////////////


/*

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView thumbnail;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }

    }
*/


    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<Image> images,RecyclerView recyclerViewlist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.images = images;
        this.mRecyclerViewlist = recyclerViewlist;
//------------moshakhas kardane inke aya be entehaye list resideheim ya na---------------

        final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this.mContext, 3);
        mRecyclerViewlist.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
                {
                    visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    if (mLayoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager)
                        firstVisibleItem = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    else if (mLayoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager)
                        firstVisibleItem = ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    else if (mLayoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
                        int[] firstVisibleItems = null;
                        firstVisibleItems = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVisibleItems);
                        if (firstVisibleItems != null && firstVisibleItems.length > 0) {
                            firstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItems[0];
                        }
                    }

                    if (isLoading) {
                        if ((totalItemCount > previousTotal)) {
                            isLoading = false;

                            previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                            Log.v("...", "Last Item Wow !");

                        }
                    }

                    if (!isLoading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                        if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                            mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                        }
                        isLoading = true;


                    }
                }
                }
        });
    }

/*
        @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {


            return images.get(position) == null ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
        }

*/

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gallery_thumbnail, parent, false);

        ImageViewHolder vh=new ImageViewHolder(itemView);
            return vh;
         /*

        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.gallery_thumbnail, parent, false);
            ImageViewHolder vh=new ImageViewHolder(view);

            return vh;
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_LOADING) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_loading_item, parent, false);
            ProgressViewHolder vh2=new ProgressViewHolder(view);

            return vh2;
        }
        return null;
         */

}


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (images.get(position) != null){


        Image image = images.get(position);

        Glide.with(mContext).load(image.getMedium())
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(((ImageViewHolder)holder).thumbnail);


        }else {

            Glide.clear(((ImageViewHolder)holder).thumbnail);
            ((ImageViewHolder) holder).thumbnail.setImageBitmap(null);
        }

        //itemhaei ke bayad neshan dadeh shavad bayad inja vared shavad
//check kardane inke kodam halate nemayesh darhale ejrast

          /*
        if (holder instanceof ImageViewHolder) {
            final ImageViewHolder myViewHolder = (ImageViewHolder) holder;
            Image image = images.get(position);
            Utils.viewMode=true;

            Glide.with(mContext).load(image.getMedium())
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(myViewHolder.thumbnail);


        }else if (holder instanceof ProgressViewHolder) {
            ProgressViewHolder loadingViewHolder = (ProgressViewHolder) holder;
            loadingViewHolder.pBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            Utils.viewMode=false;

        }
        */
        }



    public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
        void onLoadMore();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
            return images ==null ? 0 :images.size();


    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private GalleryAdapter.ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final GalleryAdapter.ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }


    }
    public static class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView thumbnail;

        public ImageViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar pBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            pBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressLoading);
        }

    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener mOnLoadMoreListener) {
        this.mOnLoadMoreListener = mOnLoadMoreListener;
    }
  
    public void setLoaded() {
        isLoading = false;
    }

    public void setPreviousTotal(boolean isLoading){

        this.isLoading = isLoading;

    }

    public int getPreviousTotal(){
        return this.previousTotal;
    }


}
```

Comment: simple you are changing list but not calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: so when you update your list after that you have to notify you adapter to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Lokesh Thanks,but where i mus call notifyDataSetChanged exactly?can you show me in my code?

Comment: tell me when you fetch images array, how long its size and r you click when you r adding images

Comment: @Lokesh when i fetch i get 8 image from server and when this progress not fully completed i click on one of image and i get that Error

Comment: Try 1 thing,  when you fetch image save in local object after when add all image add in images arrays and call notifydatachange

Comment: @Lokesh can you show me what can i do exactly?i'am new in android.If possible write it for me please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IllegalStateException: adapter's content without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896599/illegalstateexception-adapters-content-without-calling-pageradapternotifydata)